# django_cities_light no data being imported

Tags: django, geonames

I'm trying to work with `django_cities_light` and have followed the docs to a T and also referenced some other SO questions but no data is being imported.

When I open a python shell and do

```
from cities_light.models import City
c1 = City.objects.get(id=100)
```

`c1` returns

```
cities_light.models.City.DoesNotExist
```

I've ran

```
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py cities_light
```

But there is still no data.

settings.py

```
CITIES_LIGHT_TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ['en']
CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES = ['FR']
CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_CITY_TYPES = ['PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'PPLA3', 'PPLA4', 'PPLC', 'PPLF', 'PPLG', 'PPLL', 'PPLR', 'PPLS', 'STLMT',
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: why you think the city with `id=100` should be in the database?
i think the main issue is the settings  `CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES` or other filters you set.

Comment: and if you look inside the [cities15000.zip](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip) archive, there is no records start with the `100`

Comment: @BearBrown I've added my `settings.py` but when I go into admin, there are still no cities showing from `France` or any for that matter.

Comment: @BearBrown No matter what ID I put I still get the same `DoesNotExist`

Comment: when i try to execute the `City.objects.count()` it give me `616` with the same `settings` as your, what result do you have?

Comment: I get `0` ..... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190578/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-trilla).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

think i the way:
1.rollback all migration for the app

```
./manage.py migrate cities_light zero
```

next aplpy it again

```
./manage.py migrate
```

and try to do force import

```
./manage.py cities_light --force-import-all
```

may be the last command can be enough